# How to create a procedural low poly texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I will be straight forward.

I have a game where the ground looks like this (image 1).
[image: image 1]

But it actually is like this(image 2).
[image: image 2]

I want to create an image texture of it instead of two meshes glitched together. I believe I should use maybe Voronoi texture and do some tweaking? How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The *Noise Texture* is pretty close to what you want, just keep the needles of the *ColorRamp* close to each other (or choose *Constant* in the *ColorRamp* instead of *Linear* if you want the texture to be very sharp):

[image]